# AngularJS - Refreshing the model in a controller

Tags: angularjs

I am pretty new to AngularJS and got to fix a bug in prod.

There is controller

```js
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, DatamodelUser) {
    $scope.clickbutton = function (rs) {
        var usr = DatamodelUser.UserAction('xyz'); //This performs some action
        $scope.result = usr;
    }
});
```

```html
 <button ng-click="clickbutton(rs)" >OK</button>
```

What I see is DatamodelUser.UserAction is actually invoked on a button click method works only the 1st button click after the page is loaded.. the 2nd time I click a button it does not work.

After I refresh the page again and click the button then only it works.

What I think to do is after the button is clicked I am thinking of resetting the data or refreshing DatamodelUser so that each time the user clicks the button the data loads.

any help on this is appreciated, apologies if the questions are not clear I am new to this.

Comment: Please also include the code where you are setting the button onclick to DatamodelUser.UserAction

Comment: added sample code

Comment: how do you know that button is working on first click ...are you doing anything with $scope.result. and do you have an idea what Datamodel.userAction does??

Comment: Add code of `DatamodelUser`